# IronPython Downloads Confusion

Tags: ironpython

I am a bit confused about the downloads required for IronPython.

First of all in NuGet, there are 3 things:

1. IronPython
2. IronPython.StdLib
3. IronPython.Interpreter

There is also an installer located at http://ironpython.net/ and if I don't install that I get errors when importing python modules such as `os`. From the web site I get the impression that the installer and the `StdLib` in `NuGet` is the same thing but I guess it is not.

So I am wondering: what  exactly is the difference between NuGet packages and the installer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The installer includes the shell/interpreter (`ipy.exe`); the embedding libraries (in `\Platforms`) - `IronPython.dll` et al.; and the Python standard library (StdLib), all bundled together for general use. The zip package is the same.

The `IronPython` NuGet package is just the embedding libraries, the `IronPython.StdLib` package is just the standard library, and I'm not sure what `IronPython.Interpreter` is (I didn't create it) but I'd wager it's just `ipy.exe`.

If you just want to play with IronPython or run scripts from the command line, you want the installer or the zip package.

If you're embedding it in another application, you can use the packages from the installer, but I'd recommend using the NuGet packages instead. If you want to `import os` when embedding you need both `IronPython` and `IronPython.StdLib` packages, and you'll need to make sure that the `ScriptEngine` is configured to find the stdlib (it should Just Work™ but you may need to tweak; sorry this isn't better documented).